# Pie chart using Chart.js not showing up in browser

Tags: javascript, php, html, xampp, chart.js

I'm currently doing my web programming assignment where I'm tasked to create a travel blog website. For this project, I'm using HTML, CSS, JavaScript, PHP, and XAMPP. In this project, I'm responsible for the Analytics module, where the page displays the user's analytics. The following is the interface so far:

[The page has three parts, the overview, rating ratio, and most popular posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEP2T.png)

I have settled the overview and most popular posts parts, but I'm having trouble displaying the pie chart under the rating ratio part. For the rating ratio, it basically takes all the ratings that the user received from the database, and generates a pie chart showing the percentage of the user's 5 Stars to 1 Star.

Here are the structures of the tables that are related to my part, just in case it's needed as reference:

[User Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4IXJ.jpg)

[Post's Comment & Rate Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l88Vp.jpg)

[Post Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryA19.jpg)

Can anyone help me figure out why it's not showing up on my browser? I've spent the last couple of days trying to figure it out with ChatGPT, I did every single thing suggested to solve this problem but it's still not showing up.

The following is the code for the Rating Ratio part:

```
<div class="post-item-Analytics">
                    <div class="ratingRatio">
                        <strong>RATING RATIO</strong><br><br>
                        <canvas id="ratingRatioChart" width="200" height="200"></canvas><br><br>
                        <div class="ratingRatioData">
                            
                            <?php
                            // Query to get the number of ratings for the user
                            $numRatingsQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS numRatings FROM PostComRate WHERE post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM Post WHERE user_id = '1')";
                            $numRatingsResult = mysqli_query($conn, $numRatingsQuery);

                            if ($numRatingsResult && mysqli_num_rows($numRatingsResult) > 0) {
                                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($numRatingsResult);
                                $numRatings = $row['numRatings'];
                            } else {
                                $numRatings = 0; // Set a default value if the query fails or there are no ratings
                            }

                            // Query to get the number of specific rating values for the user
                            $ratingValuesQuery = "SELECT rate, COUNT(*) AS count FROM PostComRate WHERE post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM Post WHERE user_id = '1') GROUP BY rate";
                            $ratingValuesResult = mysqli_query($conn, $ratingValuesQuery);

                            if ($ratingValuesResult && mysqli_num_rows($ratingValuesResult) > 0) {
                                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ratingValuesResult)) {
                                    $ratingValue = $row['rate'];
                                    $count = $row['count'];
                                    $percentage = ($count / $numRatings) * 100;
            
                                    // Output the rating value and percentage
                                    echo "<p><strong>" . round($percentage) . "%</strong> $ratingValue Stars</p>";
                                }

                            } else {

                                // Set default values if the query fails or there are no ratings
                                $ratingValues = array(
                                '5' => 0,
                                '4' => 0,
                                '3' => 0,
                                '2' => 0,
                                '1' => 0
                                );
        
                                foreach ($ratingValues as $ratingValue => $count) {
                                    $percentage = ($count / $numRatings) * 100;
            
                                    // Output the rating value and percentage
                                    echo "<p><strong>" . round($percentage) . "%</strong> $ratingValue Stars</p>";
                                }
                            }

                            // Create an array to hold the rating values and counts
                            $ratingData = array();

                            if ($ratingValuesResult && mysqli_num_rows($ratingValuesResult) > 0) {
                                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ratingValuesResult)) {
                                    $ratingValue = $row['rate'];
                                    $count = $row['count'];
                                    $percentage = ($count / $numRatings) * 100;

                                    // Add the rating value, count, and percentage to the rating data array
                                    $ratingData[] = array(
                                        'rating' => $ratingValue,
                                        'count' => $count,
                                        'percentage' => round($percentage)
                                    );

                                    // Output the rating value and percentage
                                    echo "<p><strong>" . round($percentage) . "%</strong> $ratingValue Stars</p>";
                                }
                            } 
                            
                            else {
                                // Set default values if the query fails or there are no ratings
                                $ratingValues = array(
                                    '5' => 0,
                                    '4' => 0,
                                    '3' => 0,
                                    '2' => 0,
                                    '1' => 0
                                    );
            
                                    foreach ($ratingValues as $ratingValue => $count) {
                                        $percentage = ($count / $numRatings) * 100;
                
                                        // Output the rating value and percentage
                                        echo "<p><strong>" . round($percentage) . "%</strong> $ratingValue Stars</p>";
                                }
                            }
                            ?>

                            <script>
                            // Get the canvas element
                            var chartCanvas = document.getElementById("ratingRatioChart");

                            // Extract the rating labels, counts, and percentages from the PHP rating data
                            var ratingLabels = <?php echo json_encode(array_column($ratingData, 'rating')); ?>;
                            var ratingCounts = <?php echo json_encode(array_column($ratingData, 'count')); ?>;
                            var ratingPercentages = <?php echo json_encode(array_column($ratingData, 'percentage')); ?>;

                            // Create the chart using Chart.js
                            new Chart(chartCanvas, {
                                type: 'pie',
                                data: {
                                labels: ratingLabels,
                                datasets: [{
                                    data: ratingCounts,
                                    backgroundColor: ['#ff6384', '#36a2eb', '#ffce56', '#4bc0c0', '#9966ff']
                                }]
                                },
                                options: {
                                legend: {
                                    position: 'bottom'
                                }
                                }
                            });

                            // Add console.log statements to check the data
                            console.log(ratingLabels, ratingCounts, ratingPercentages);

                            </script>
                            
                        </div>
```

Edit!

I want to clarify that I have included the js file in my code.

- [image: Code after PHP has run]
- [image: Errors in the browser console]

I already did my research on the errors, and I was told that the errors aren't related to the chart not loading in the browser.

Comment: I assume you have included the js file such as `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>` ?

Comment: Please post (also) the code after php has run, e.g., from the page source  in the browser (you may remove redundant elements if too long). Also, see if there are errors in the browser console, and if there are none please state so in your post.

Comment: @KenLee Yes, I have included the js file, and I also tried the downloading method.

Comment: @kikon Hi, I have added them in my post.

Comment: As you can see, from both the javascript code and the `console.log` result, your javascript variables `ratingLabels` and `ratingCounts` are empty arrays. That means that both the `data` and the `labels` of the chart are empty, so the chart has nothing to show. This is most likely caused by the fact the php variable `$ratingData` is also an empty array. So I'd start debugging the php code by, for instance, displaying the intermediate results (with the likes of `echo`, `print_r`, and `var_dump`) and looking in the browser source code what they displayed.

Comment: Unrelated to that, which is the main problem, I see that in the chart configuration, you placed the `legend` directly under `options` - it should be (at least in version 4 of charts) under `options.plugins`; that is: `options: {plugins: {legend: {position: 'bottom'}}}`, see the [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#configuration-options).

Comment: Also, it is not recommended to use `<canvas id=... width="200" height="200"></canvas>` because the size properties of the canvas might get overwitten by the charts functions; instead include the `canvas` in a `div` element that only contains the `canvas` and has the sizes set in css, like: `<div style="width:200px; height:200px"><canvas id=...></canvas></div>`, see this [doc link](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/responsive.html#important-note).

Comment: Those console warnings are regular occurrences in chrome and, indeed, they are not relevant to your problem.

Comment: In this case, I used AJAX and the rest will be handled by Javascript